# Is it legal to remove Metro apps from Windows 10?

Tags: software

I wonder whether it is legal to debloat and remove ads from Windows 10?

Comment: It is if the software license doesn't prohibit it.  Have you read the license?

Comment: Has *anyone* read the license?

Comment: @user6726 I doubt it. I think we have a friend who likes posting nonsensical and uniformed answers as well :P

Answer (score 0):

The software licence doesn't prohibit it so yes.